# DestinationViewController Segue and UINavigationController swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue

So I have a prepareForSegue method like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "fromEventTableToAddEvent" {

        let addEventViewController: AddEventViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddEventViewController

        addEventViewController.newTagArray = newTagArray

    }
}
```

However, at runtime the app crashes and logs spit out this message:

> Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController'

The error comes because the addEventController is embedded in a navigation controller, however I'm not sure how I would set up the segue so that the destinationViewController is set to the NavigationController, but also allow me to pass variables in the prepareForSegue method to the addEventController

So how would I do this using Swift?

I extremely appreciate your help and time you may offer in response. It helps alot

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You only need to access the navigation controller's topViewController, which will be the AddEventViewController. Here is the code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "fromEventTableToAddEvent" {

        let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let addEventViewController = nav.topViewController as! AddEventViewController

        addEventViewController.newTagArray = newTagArray

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple, easy.

Comment: @reggie Swift 3 is pretty much the same thing.  let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let topicVC = nav.topViewController as! TopicsViewController

Answer (score 0):

All that is needed explicitly is to create an object off the segue.destination class and downcast it to your desired ViewController.