# SIGABRT signal with DetailViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am extremely new at Swift and still figuring out the Swift/Objective-C syntax and libraries. I am trying to recreate a simple list of pictures I can view on a different image view.  Below is the code and the error message, could someone please guide me in the right direction.

import UIKit

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var objects = [AnyObject]()


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
            self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 320.0, height: 600.0)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!

        let items = fm.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path, error: nil)

        for item in items as! [String] {
            if item.hasPrefix("IMG_") {
                objects.append(item)
            }
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Segues

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {

                let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
                detailViewController.detailItem = objects[indexPath.row] as? String
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        let object: (AnyObject) = objects[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = object as? String
        return cell
    }

}
```

I am getting the error in this block of code specifically:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {

                let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
                detailViewController.detailItem = objects[indexPath.row] as? String
            }
        }
    }
```

The error message in the console comes up as:

> Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10a979698) to 'Project1.DetailViewController' (0x1090f27a0).

Comment: Can you share what line it is failing on?

Comment: the line failing is    let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

Comment: This has nothing to do with Objective-C.  Please do not abuse tags, especially language tags, as that effect syntax highlighting in posts.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
```

With this:

```
let nav = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
let detailViewController = nav.topViewController as! DetailViewController
```

Solution modified from: [DestinationViewController Segue and UINavigationController swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573635/destinationviewcontroller-segue-and-uinavigationcontroller-swift)

Comment: Rather than copying someone else's answer, the appropriate action here would be to mark the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think sender is the destination view controller? It's not.

What you want is:

```
if let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController {
```

But @nhgrif has a point: you are segue'ing to a nav controller.

Comment: This stops the crash, but still doesn't provide desired results.  `detailViewController` would be `nil` and this `if` wouldn't enter.

Comment: Why would it be nil? You downvote people for nothing and provide no details. Perfect.

Comment: If the segue was created on the storyboard it should have the destination controller automatically.

Comment: Did you read the error message?  The `destinationViewController` is a `UINavigationController`.  Your answer still tries casting it as something else.  The cast will fail.