# Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController

Tags: ios, segue

I'm trying to show more details once the user click on each row.
I'm using the prepareForSegue.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {


        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
            (segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController).detailItem = object
        }

    }
}
```

but once the user click on each row I'm getting the following error msg:

**Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1c73e1c)**

Comment: I think you have embedded uinavigation controller to view controller, thats why getting error.

Comment: This may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573635/destinationviewcontroller-segue-and-uinavigationcontroller-swift